# How get a named range from an excel sheet using ExcelDataReader.Dataset

Tags: c#, excel, named-ranges, exceldatareader

I am using the [ExcelDataReader.Dataset](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) package to read in .xlsx files and store specific sheets as a `DataTable`, like so:

```
public void SelectWorkbookClick(string s)
{
    string fileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", WorkbookFolder, Workbook);

    using (var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    { 
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {
            FrontSheet = reader.AsDataSet().Tables[FrontSheetName];
            RearSheet = reader.AsDataSet().Tables[RearSheetName];
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for reading in sheets, however my `.xlsx` file has named ranges in which I need to access.

I have had a look around and cannot not find any support for this, does anyone know of anyways I could go around this?

Comment: Alas its not implemented (yet?) https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/issues/25

Comment: @user8728340 yeah saw that thread, looks like they never got around to implementing it :(

Comment: Side-Note: Please call `reader.AsDataSet()` once! `var ds = reader.AsDataSet();` then use its tables - HTH ;).