# How to read values from Defined Names (Named Ranges)?

Tags: c#, excel, exceldatareader

I'm using ExcelDataReader to read XLS files and it's working fine but I don't know how to read Defined Names.

I am able to read file contents into a DataSet:

```
var excelDataSet = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration 
{
    ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration { UseHeaderRow = true }
});
```

I then take the first table from the contents:

```
DataTable? table = excelDataSet.Tables["MyTable"];
```

And I can then loop through rows and columns with

```
string cellValue = table.Rows[rowNumber][colNumber].ToString();
```

But this doesn't give me values from the so-called **Defined Names** (Named Ranges). How to read those?

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not supported in ExcelDataReader -
See previous stack overflow question: [How get a named range from an excel sheet using ExcelDataReader.Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607151/how-get-a-named-range-from-an-excel-sheet-using-exceldatareader-dataset)